# Server Error - Could not find a part of the path 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\Temp\1.png'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file, asp.net-mvc-4

I am getting the following error whilst trying to upload an image to my website.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Could not find a part of the path
>   'C:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\Temp\1.png'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not
>   find a part of the path 'C:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\Temp\1.png'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path
>   'C:\home\site\wwwroot\App_Data\Temp\1.png'.]
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   +353    System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share,
>   Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs,
>   String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean
>   checkHost) +1326    System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode
>   mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize,
>   FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy) +60
>   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode) +55
>   System.Web.HttpPostedFile.SaveAs(String filename) +94
>   System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper.SaveAs(String filename) +14
>   RoomAuditSystem.Controllers.HomeController.Index(HttpPostedFileBase
>   file) +96    lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +104 
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters) +14
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +157
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +27
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +32
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
>   +50    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   +225    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +34
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
>   +26    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +100
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +27
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +22
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +28    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +9
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +9744373    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Here is the section of code which handles this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Temp"), fileName);
            file.SaveAs(path);

            // create a barcode reader instance
            IBarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();
            // load a bitmap
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(path);

            Bitmap resized = new Bitmap(bitmap, new Size(400, 400));

            // detect and decode the barcode inside the bitmap
            var result = reader.Decode(resized);

            bitmap.Dispose();

            // Delete file once we have finished with it
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(path);
            }

            // do something with the result
            if (result != null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Create", "Audit", new { roomID = result.Text });
                //txtDecoderType.Text = result.BarcodeFormat.ToString();
            }

            // Decode error
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }

        // File error
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }      
    }
```

It works fine on my local machine, but doesn't seem to be working when I publish it online. I definitely had a directory called App_Data and another directory within that called Temp in the root on my site.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you have Temp folder in App_Data?

Comment: what is the Build Action set to for the image(s) in your App_Data\Temp directory?

Comment: Have you checked the Permissions on the target directory?

Comment: @CamBruce what does that mean? Can you please elaborate? And Yes Ehsan, I do have that folder.

Comment: each file will have a 'build action' property in the Properties window of Visual Studio. It will usually be set to 'Build' or 'Content' depending on what type of file it is

Comment: @CamBruce I see, the image isn't actually permanently on the server, I simply just upload it and then delete it after its been analysed so I can't see it in visual studio. dan m, do you mean permissions in Windows? I have read this before and checked and my account has permissions but there was no option for IIS or something that i could find?

Comment: Check the AppPool that your site is running against in IIS, then check that has permissions to read and write to App_Data.

Comment: @danm what's the AppPool? Sorry this is all new to me and where do I find IIS? I have a folder on my computer called IISExpress but can't find any runnables there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exception is explicit. Part of that path doesn't exist. Importantly, `App_Data` is not included during a publish, so just because it exists in your project locally, doesn't mean it's actually there on your production server. Other than that, check the whole path, i.e. you must have a `home` directory directly on your C drive, which must have a `site` directory, etc.

Again, there's just no way to get that exception if everything is right. Some part of that path is incorrect or does not exist.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I've now removed App_Data and moved Temp to the root on my application and published again. I believe the C:\home\site\wwwroot bit is made by the company I am hosting with but it still isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix this with Chris' explanation. The folder 'Temp' wasn't present even though I published it alongside the whole application. I'm assuming because this folder was empty, it wasn't getting published with everything else. So I manually published that individual folder and hey presto - it works!